# Using WordPress Multisite to manage multiple projects?

Tags: themes, multisite

I currently use WordPress for most of my projects, the way I manage them is creating a folder for each in my local environment each containing a WP install which in times makes it a paint to maintain, upgrade and takes more space.

I was looking at WP Multisite and I was wondering if I could use it to create multiple projects with the same WP installation but ran into a problem, when I finish a project using my current method I just send my client a SQL Dump of my DB, tell them to replace the URL and install all the files/folders to his server and it works fine. But WP Multisite creates an unique folder and DB structure which makes it difficult to do this since most of my clients won't be using MU but regular Wordpress installations.

So is there an easy way to "export" a WP MS site to use it on a regular WP install? Or should I stick to having multiple WP copies?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I edited your question to Multisite unless you are actually referring to the OLD WordPress MU that was separate from WordPress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export/Import like you would the data for any other WordPress install:

On the development site:

1. `Dashboard -> Tools -> Export -> All Content` (save file)
2. Package up the Theme files as "theme-name.zip"
3. Make note of any custom settings

On the live site:

1. Install the custom Theme
2. `Dashboard -> Tools -> Import -> WordPress data file (upload file)
3. Change any custom settings noted above

EDIT:

If you still want to try a database export, you could try network-enabling one of the many database-backup Plugins in the repository, such as WP-DBmanager, and running it from your dev site.

Comment: Do this feature copy everything? I remember using it a while back but it didn't export everything I think custom fields didn't get copied over for example.

Comment: As far as I know, it will copy everything. Note that you'll need to perform the import on the live site, in order to download/upload attachments, as they are not part of the WXR file.

Comment: Although that takes care of the Export, I think Javier was aiming at the database transfer from his multisite install to the client's standalone install...

Comment: The only things not picked up in the WXR are settings and users. All of the actual *content* is included.

Comment: I see, let me try and see how it goes then